# How to get notified when the application window size changes on PC/MAC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to look for a way to get any kind of notification/callback when the user changes the application window size while on PC/MAC.

i have tried looking everywhere, stackoverflow, unity forum, reddit and i have yet to find anything except trying to check it on Update or using a co-routine.

my goal is whenever the user is changing the application window size i am fixing the size application window the user set to the closest resolution possible to the display's supported aspect ratio.

thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the initial window sizes and than compare them like

```
public float targetAspetctRatio;

private int lastWidth;
private int lastHeight;

private void Start()
{
    lastWidth = Screen.width;
    lastHeight = Screen.height;

    // You could get the targetAspetctRatio also from the device like
    targetAspetctRatio = (float)Screen.currentResolution.with / Screen.currentResolution.height;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if(lastWidth != Screen.width || lastHeight != Screen.height || !Mathf.Approximately((float)Screen.width/Screen.height, targetAspetctRatio))
    {
        ScreenSizeChanged();
    }
}
```

or with a timer for not checking every frame

```
private float timer=0;
public float Interval = 0.5f;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    timer-= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer > 0) return;

    timer = Interval;

    if(lastWidth != Screen.width || lastHeight != Screen.height || !Mathf.Approximately((float)Screen.width/Screen.height, targetAspetctRatio))
    {
        ScreenSizeChanged();
    }
}
```

or with a Coroutine

```
public float Interval = 0.5f;

private void Start()
{
    lastWidth = Screen.width;
    lastHeight = Screen.height;

    // You could get the targetAspetctRatio also from the device like
    targetAspetctRatio = (float)Screen.currentResolution.with / Screen.currentResolution.height;

    StartCoroutine(CheckSize);
}

private IEnumertor CheckSize()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(lastWidth != Screen.width || lastHeight != Screen.height || !Mathf.Approximately((float)Screen.width/Screen.height, targetAspetctRatio))
        {
            ScreenSizeChanged();
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Offset);
    }
}
```

---

To set an aspect ratio do either set it based on the height

```
Screen.SetResolution(Screen.height * targetAspetctRatio, Screen.height, false);
```

or based on the width

```
Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width,  Screen.width / targetAspetctRatio, false);
```

You have to decide which way to go .. in doubt at least one that fits into the screen. Something like

```
private void ScreenSizeChanged ()
{
    // Try to go by width first
    // Check if new height would fit
    if(Screen.width <= screen.currentResolution.width && Screen.width / targetAspetctRatio <= Screen.currentResolution.height)
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width,  Screen.width / targetAspetctRatio, false);
    }

    // By height as fallback
    // Check if new width would fit display
    else if(Screen.height <= Screen.currentResolution.height && Screen.height * targetAspetctRatio <= Screen.currentResolution.width)
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(Screen.height * targetAspetctRatio, Screen.height, false);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing or maybe reset?
        Screen.SetResolution(lastWidth, lastHeight, false);
    }

    // Don't fortget to store the changed values 
    lastWidth = Screen.width;
    lastHeight = Screen.height;
}
```

[Screen.currentResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-currentResolution.html) returns the display's max resolution not the current window size.

Comment: your solution is a bit overkill considering you do it in lateupdate, im currently doing mine in a co-routine that starts on awake and waiting about 0.5sec in the co-routine so it will come out that i am checking only 2 times per second instead of the frames per sec (if i had 60 frames then it will check 60 times per second) but i am trying to find a way to listen to that instead of checking every X time.

Comment: you can also wait in the `LateUpdate` if you want to ... I don't think there is another way for checking that

Comment: ofcourse there is some overhead but I'ld say checking only two floats every frame or interval is not that performance intense

Comment: i will mark your main post as the answer because you gave few solutions which includes both a coroutine and a lateupdate which both are basically solutions to the issue also its a good way of thinking for other solution if someone doesnt like those 2.
thanks :)

Comment: @aDeadPixel Glad to help :)